# How to programatically set markers on Windows Media video in c#

Tags: c#, video, media-player, activex, video-player

In Visual Studio 2019 for Windows in c# for the component axWindowsMediaPlayer we have the event MarkerHit that is triggered when the video player hits a marker. Now I am puzzled at how can I add the markers into the video programmatically.
e.g.
add markers at time 00:01.23, 00:01.54 and 00.02.14

This is for triggering specific actions in the desktop app when the video hit the marks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't get this to work, try the PlayCtrl from LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). The control has an event called TrackingPositionChanged. In the event handler, you can check the value of the [CurrentPosition Property](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/multimedia/mm/playctrl-currentposition.html) which gives the playback position in seconds. Comparing the position to your desired time marker points allows you to take custom actions in your application. You can obtain a [free evaluation here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).